# Making combo boxes update 

Tags: java, swing, combobox

Right so I have a simple problem, I have three combo boxes and a method that chooses a new array value for the 3rd combo box.

How do I make the 3rd combo box update when I use the first two combo boxes result to create a new array for the 3rd combo box.

This has to happen in real time so combo box 3 has to update every time 1 or 2 updates ( I assume I add them to the action performed but I haven't had any luck ).

PS. I'm doing this with swings JComboBoxes

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add EventListeners to the first two combo boxes which will be notified when the combo boxes change.  This event could then be used to do whatever modifications you need to the third combo box.

This page will explain to you all the details of EventListeners: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html

Comment: +1 for the tutorial link. I like to use an ActionListener for this since only a single event is generated. You can also use an ItemListener although two events are generated. One for the deselection of the old item and one for the selection of the new item.

Comment: I have several action listeners for each combo box already which take the information from the combo box and assign it to a variable, the main bit I can't get to work is making the combo box actually update.  I tried using addItem but it doesn't seem to work ( this is contained in a method thats run in the previous two combo boxes listeners.